# Extract 2 levels nested json array align with another column Presto

Tags: sql, arrays, json, nested, presto

Well the solution how to extract a json array of any depth is pretty clear explained in [Extract complex nested JSON array in Presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59522129/extract-complex-nested-json-array-in-presto).
But it is not clear for me how to align this extract with one or more columns which could be in an initial dataset. When I just add the column to select statement with cross joins it definitely matches all possible variants but not align.
Well, for example I have this table nested is string

```
id | nested
---+------------------------------------------
m1 |[{"item_detail":[{"itemid":"4702385896","modelid":"8307307322","quantity":"1"}],"shopid":"128449080"},{"item_detail":[{"itemid":"3902478595","modelid":"8306561848","quantity":"1"}],"shopid":"128344123"},{"item_detail":[{"itemid":"7906381345","modelid":"9745718882","quantity":"1"}],"shopid":"361421097"}]
m2 |[{"item_detail":[{"itemid":"4702123489","modelid":"7732834327","quantity":"4"}],"shopid":"128449080"},{"item_detail":[{"itemid":"7726362758","modelid":"0039272735","quantity":"1"}],"shopid":"843877394"},{"item_detail":[{"itemid":"5534553459","modelid":"3345772908","quantity":"1"}],"shopid":"776261981"}]
m3 |[{"item_detail":[{"itemid":"6663652234","modelid":"0929837271","quantity":"3"}],"shopid":"128449080"},{"item_detail":[{"itemid":"0093298282","modelid":"3422288844","quantity":"1"}],"shopid":"093847726"},{"item_detail":[{"itemid":"7362712636","modelid":"1111181733","quantity":"1"}],"shopid":"837274646"}]
..............................................
```

So, I need the table with aligned rows by id and extract itemid, modelid and quantity from `nested` where `shopid = 128449080` like this:

```
id | itemid     | modelid    | quantity |shopid
---+------------+------------+----------+---------
m1 | 4702385896 | 8307307322 | 1        |128449080
m2 | 4702123489 | 7732834327 | 4        |128449080
m3 | 6663652234 | 0929837271 | 3        |128449080
```

OK to extract and join itemid, modelid and quantity I use

```
select
  json_extract_scalar(item_detail, '$.itemid') as itemid,
  json_extract_scalar(item_detail, '$.modelid') as modelid,
  json_extract_scalar(item_detail, '$.quantity') as quantity
from dataset,
unnest(cast(json_parse(nested) as array(json))) as x(shopping),
unnest(cast(json_extract(shopping, '$.item_detail') as array(json))) as y(item_detail)
where json_extract_scalar(shopping, '$.shopid') = 128449080
```

Well when I have only two levels and only one extract in each using cross join is straightforward. But when I have more then two levels or more then one extract for each level cross join gives redundant matches.
What is workaround for this case?

Comment: I'm not following - what is the problem here? What is not working in the provided query (except that `where` should be `where json_extract_scalar(shopping, '$.shopid') = '128449080'` at least for earlier presto versions). If problem is with some another query - please provide a [mre]

Comment: @GuruStron the query I posted works fine but it gives correct result only for second level depth and matches
`itemid | modelid | quantity`
I need properly match
`id | itemid | modelid | quantity | shopid`

Comment: changing it's `select` to `select  id,  json_extract_scalar(item_detail, '$.itemid') as itemid,  json_extract_scalar(item_detail, '$.modelid') as modelid,  json_extract_scalar(item_detail, '$.quantity') as quantity,  json_extract_scalar(shopping, '$.shopid') shopid` works just fine for me producing the results you have posted in _"like this"_ table.

Comment: @GuruStron thank you. I overestimate the complexity of the query trying to cross join extracts from nested column (across different levels) and regular column instead just unnest them straightforward